# Disabling an extension for php-fpm

Tags: php, multithreading, nginx

I'm trying to set up a server environment where I would like to have php-fpm (7.0.0RC7) running along with nginx and have multi-threading option for command line. Hence I compiled php myself with zts enabled and got it running with my nginx server.

Problem is that when I enable pthreads extension, php-fpm would not start. Running commands such as 'php threads.php' (file consuming multiple threads), works fine though.

Is it possible to have a separate `php.ini` for php-fpm service? Or have a particular extension turned on/off for php-fpm?

Any pointers would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php) page for configuration files:

> If `php-SAPI.ini` exists (where SAPI is the SAPI in use, so, for example, `php-cli.ini` or `php-apache.ini`), it is used instead of `php.ini`. The SAPI name can be determined with `php_sapi_name()`.

Comment: Perfect! I ran php_sapi_name() from command line and it showed 'cli', so just needed to add `php-cli.ini` with the custom configuration added. Thanks!